# Architecture in Node JS wirh Controller, Service and Repository

Tags: node.js, service, callback, repository, domain-driven-design

In order to keep clean architecture of my node.js I have controllers, services and repositories.

Data flow: controller -> service -> repository -> service -> controller. 
In this flow (in simple user story) repository returns data to service and service to controller. But repository should process requests to external storage.

Right now I have the callback difficulty, how can I implement a nested callback between controller and repository?

My Controller:

```
exports.clientes_get = async function (req, res) {

    Cliente.find(function(err,params) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

            res.json(params);
        });
}
```

My Service:

```
 ClienteGet(req) {
        var response;

        repo.get(req.params.clienteId, (err, res) => {
            response = res;
            //console.log(response); -> have data
        });

        //console.log(response); -> doesnt have data
        return response;
    };
```

My Repository:

```
get(clienteId, data) {
        mongoose.model('Cliente').findById(clienteId, data);
    };
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using Callbacks

If you insist on using callbacks:

**Controller:**

```js
// notice that the `async` here was not necessary
exports.clientes_get = function (req, res) {
    // the `function(err, params) {...}` here is your callback
    ClienteGet(req, function(err, params) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(params);
    });
}
```

**Service:**

```js
ClienteGet(req, callback) {
    // simply pass the callback argument directly to the `repo.get` call
    repo.get(req.params.clienteId, callback);
};
```

**Repository:**

```js
get(clienteId, callback) {
    // again, just pass the callback here
    mongoose.model('Cliente').findById(clienteId, callback);
};
```

## Using Promises

I personally recommend wrapping you code in
[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises),
because they are more flexible than callbacks, and modern JavaScript uses
Promises heavily. It's pretty much the new standard... In fact, the `async` /
`await` syntax is leveraging Promises under the hood.

Here's a rough sketch of how you could use Promises:

**Controller:**

```js
exports.clientes_get = function (req, res) {
    return ClienteGet(req)
        .then((data) => {
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.send(err);
        });
}
```

**Service:**

```js
ClienteGet(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        repo.get(req.params.clienteId, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(res);
            //console.log(response); -> have data
        });
    });
};
```

**Repository:**

```js
get(clienteId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongoose.model('Cliente').findById(clienteId, function(err, document) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(document);
        });
    });
};
```